# ¿Cual es la manera de usar httprio?

Tags: webservice, delphi

Quisiera saber como hacer en delphi para consumir el web service de AFIP de facturacion electronica. El caso es que importe la direccion del servicio con WSDL Importer.

Pero segun las especificaciones se debe enviar un xml de solicitud con los datos del comprobante. Pero con el WSDL importer obtengo esto:

```
ServiceSoap = interface(IInvokable)
['{05274D74-5C3D-E536-980E-D9CE5D67F5D9}']
function  FECAESolicitar(const Auth: FEAuthRequest; const FeCAEReq: FECAERequest): FECAEResponse; 
 stdcall;
function  FECompTotXRequest(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): FERegXReqResponse; stdcall;
function  FEDummy: DummyResponse; stdcall;
function  FECompUltimoAutorizado(const Auth: FEAuthRequest; const PtoVta: Integer; const CbteTipo: 
 Integer): FERecuperaLastCbteResponse; stdcall;
function  FECompConsultar(const Auth: FEAuthRequest; const FeCompConsReq: FECompConsultaReq): 
 FECompConsultaResponse; stdcall;
function  FECAEARegInformativo(const Auth: FEAuthRequest; const FeCAEARegInfReq: FECAEARequest): 
 FECAEAResponse; stdcall;
function  FECAEASolicitar(const Auth: FEAuthRequest; const Periodo: Integer; const Orden: SmallInt): 
 FECAEAGetResponse; stdcall;
function  FECAEASinMovimientoConsultar(const Auth: FEAuthRequest; const CAEA: string; const PtoVta: 
Integer): FECAEASinMovConsResponse; stdcall;
function  FECAEASinMovimientoInformar(const Auth: FEAuthRequest; const PtoVta: Integer; const CAEA: 
 string): FECAEASinMovResponse; stdcall;
function  FECAEAConsultar(const Auth: FEAuthRequest; const Periodo: Integer; const Orden: SmallInt): 
  FECAEAGetResponse; stdcall;
function  FEParamGetCotizacion(const Auth: FEAuthRequest; const MonId: string): FECotizacionResponse; 
 stdcall;
function  FEParamGetTiposTributos(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): FETributoResponse; stdcall;
function  FEParamGetTiposMonedas(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): MonedaResponse; stdcall;
function  FEParamGetTiposIva(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): IvaTipoResponse; stdcall;
function  FEParamGetTiposOpcional(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): OpcionalTipoResponse; stdcall;
function  FEParamGetTiposConcepto(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): ConceptoTipoResponse; stdcall;
function  FEParamGetPtosVenta(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): FEPtoVentaResponse; stdcall;
function  FEParamGetTiposCbte(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): CbteTipoResponse; stdcall;
function  FEParamGetTiposDoc(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): DocTipoResponse; stdcall;
function  FEParamGetTiposPaises(const Auth: FEAuthRequest): FEPaisResponse; stdcall;
end;
```

como veran el metodo FECAESolicitar notomaun xml sino un objeto FEAuthRequest,otro FeCAERequest.

El caso es que entonces debo crear estos dos objetos y llenarlo en lugar de crear el xml de la factura?

Porque al hacer:

```
    procedure TComprobante.envio();
var
RIOFactura:THTTPRIO;
CUITEmisor:string;
      hoy:TDate;
request:FEAuthRequest;
archivoini:TIniFile;
cae:FECAERequest;
content:FECAEResponse;

fecae:FECAEDetResponse;
cabecera:FECAECabRequest;
detalle:FECAEDetRequest;
movimiento:ArrayOfFECAEDetRequest;
error:ArrayOfErr;
RioComp:THTTPRIO;
responseUltCte:FERecuperaLastCbteResponse;
resp:ArrayOfFECAEDetRequest;
begin

     hoy:=StrToDate(FormatDateTime('yy/mm/dd',now));
    archivoini:=TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'caja.ini');
    CUITEmisor:= archivoini.ReadString('AFIP','CUIT','');
    //creamos objeto request
   request:=FEAuthRequest.Create;
   request.Token:=self.token;
   request.sign:=self.sign;
   request.Cuit:= StrToInt64(CUITEmisor);

   //obtenemos ultimo comprobante asociado.
    RioComp:=THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  with RIOComp do
    begin
      WSDLLocation:='https://wswhomo.afip.gov.ar/wsfev1/service.asmx?WSDL';
      Port:='ServiceSoap';
      Service:='Service';

    end;
    //objeto de respuesta
    responseUltCte:=FERecuperaLastCbteResponse.Create;
    //invocamos el metodo
   responseUltCte:=(RioComp as serviceSoap).FECompUltimoAutorizado(request,1,011);
    error:=responseUltCte.Errors;

   if error<>nil then
       begin
         ShowMessage(error[0].Msg);
       end;
   //creamos cabecera del comprobante
   cabecera:=FECAECabRequest.Create;
   cabecera.CantReg:=DataModule1.cdsticket.RecordCount;
   cabecera.PtoVta:=1;
   cabecera.CbteTipo:=011;
   //creamos el detalle
   detalle:=FECAEDetRequest.Create;
   detalle.Concepto:=1;
   detalle.DocTipo:=80;
   detalle.DocNro:=20346787717;
   detalle.CbteDesde:=responseUltCte.CbteNro + 1;

   detalle.CbteHasta:=responseUltCte.CbteNro + 1;
   detalle.CbteFch:=FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd',now);
   detalle.ImpTotal:=DataModule1.cdstickettotal.AsVariant;

   detalle.ImpTotConc:=0;
   detalle.ImpNeto:=DataModule1.cdstickettotal.AsVariant;
   detalle.ImpOpEx:=0;
   detalle.ImpTrib:=0;
   detalle.ImpIVA:=0;
   detalle.FchVtoPago:=DateToStr(hoy);
   detalle.MonId:='PES';
   detalle.MonCotiz:=0;
   //movieminto
  SetLength(movimiento,1);
   movimiento[0]:=detalle;
   //creamos el objeto request
   cae:=FECAERequest.Create;

   //asignamos la cabecera
   cae.FeCabReq:=cabecera;
   cae.FeDetReq:=movimiento;
   content:=FECAEResponse.Create;
   //creamos objeto rio
  RIOFactura:=THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  with RIOFactura do
    begin
      WSDLLocation:='https://wswhomo.afip.gov.ar/wsfev1/service.asmx?WSDL';
      Port:='ServiceSoap';
      Service:='Service';

    end;
    //invocamos el metodo
   content:=(RIOFactura as serviceSoap).FECAESolicitar(request,cae);

      if content.Errors<>nil then
       begin
          ShowMessage(content.Errors[0].Msg);
       end
       else
       begin


         ShowMessage(content.FeDetResp[0].CAE);
       end;





end;
```

Fallan los tipos obviamente,el metodo delhttprionotoma un xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque has explicado muchas cosas, ho has concretado mucho las dudas que tienes. O si te da un error, ¿qué error te está dando?

De todas formas te adjunto un código donde se usan el método dummy que posee el `WebService` y una  lamada a otro de los métodos (`FEParamGetTiposDoc`) para obtener una lista de elementos, que en mi caso falla por temas de autentificación.
La llamada a los otros son similares.

Ahí también puedes ver cómo tratar el resultado en caso correcto y en caso de error. Basta con que pongas un Memo en un formulario y un botón con este código.

```
var
  dummy:DummyResponse;
  auth:FEAuthRequest;
  tdRes:DocTipoResponse;
  i:integer;
begin
  // dummy para test
  dummy := (HTTPRIO1 as serviceSoap).FEDummy;
  mmLog.Lines.Add(dummy.AppServer);
  mmLog.Lines.Add(dummy.DbServer);
  mmLog.Lines.Add(dummy.AuthServer);

  // Crear autentificacion
  auth := FEAuthRequest.Create;
  try
    auth.Token := 'token';
    auth.Sign := 'sign';
    auth.Cuit := 666;

    // Llamada al método para obtener Lista de Tipos de doc.
    tdRes := (HTTPRIO1 as serviceSoap).FEParamGetTiposDoc(Auth);

    // resultado OK
    if (Length(tdRes.ResultGet) > 0) then  begin
      for i := 0 to high( tdRes.ResultGet ) do
        mmLog.lines.Add(tdRes.ResultGet[i].id.ToString + ' || ' +
                        tdRes.ResultGet[i].Desc + ' || '+
                        tdRes.ResultGet[i].FchDesde + ' || ' +
                        tdRes.ResultGet[i].FchHasta);
    end;

    // resultado erróneo?
    if (Length(tdRes.Errors) > 0) then
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + tdRes.Errors[0].Msg + sLineBreak +
                  'Código: ' + tdRes.Errors[0].Code.ToString);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(auth);
  end;
```

Comment: Gracias amigo..voy a modificar la pregunta con el código que cree. no me da ningún error pero no me devuelve el CAE. Aparece el mensaje vació, nose si estoy accediendo mal al array de CAE o que

Comment: Sigo obteniendo el CAE vacio, de que manera puedo mandar un xml en vez de utilizar los metodos del wsdl importer?